# perf kvm Failed to open [], continuing without symbols

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, kvm, perf

I am trying to monitor guest OS with perf kvm. I have recorded the performance using perf kvm record option and generated the report using perf kvm report. For record and report, I used the guest OS's kallsyms and modules as explained [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Virtualization_Tuning_and_Optimization_Guide/index.html#sect-Virtualization_Tuning_Optimization_Guide-Monitoring_Tools-perf_kvm).

The problem is that when I generate the reports using perf kvm report, a lot of 'Shared Object's are unknown because perf kvm report cant find symbols. Below is the terminal output when I run report.

```
root@computer1:/# perf kvm --guest --guestmodules=modules report -i perf.data --force > waste
Failed to open [ext4], continuing without symbols
Failed to open [jbd2], continuing without symbols
Failed to open [virtio_blk], continuing without symbols
Failed to open [dm_mod], continuing without symbols
Failed to open [virtio_pci], continuing without symbols
Failed to open [virtio_ring], continuing without symbols
```

And below is part of the output which I redirected to a file where you can easily see the 'unknowns'.

```
# To display the perf.data header info, please use --header/--header-only options.
#
#
# Total Lost Samples: 0
#
# Samples: 324K of event 'cycles'
# Event count (approx.): 181799817277
#
# Overhead  Command  Shared Object            Symbol                        
# ........  .......  .......................  ..............................
#
     1.30%  :28468   [unknown]                [u] 0x00007f3ae0262875        
     0.88%  :28468   [unknown]                [u] 0x00007f451f32d114        
     0.84%  :28468   [unknown]                [u] 0x00007f451f32d11d        
     0.49%  :28468   [unknown]                [u] 0x00007f451f32d118        
     0.45%  :28468   [guest.kernel.kallsyms]  [g] 0xffffffff8109aca3        
     0.43%  :28468   [unknown]                [u] 0x00007f3ae04c8891        
     0.42%  :28468   [guest.kernel.kallsyms]  [g] 0xffffffff810aa367        
     0.39%  :28468   [unknown]                [u] 0x000000343ca0a659        
     0.37%  :28468   [unknown]                [u] 0x00007f3ae04c8751        
     0.28%  :28468   [unknown]                [u] 0x000000343ca0b7c1        
     0.26%  :28468   [unknown]                [u] 0x000000343ca09223        
     0.25%  :28468   [unknown]                [u] 0x00007f451f32d116        
     0.23%  :28468   [unknown]                [u] 0x00007f3ae04c873e        
     0.21%  :28468   [guest.kernel.kallsyms]  [g] 0xffffffff8100c43f        
     0.20%  :28468   [unknown]                [u] 0x000000343ca09220        
     0.19%  :28468   [unknown]                [u] 0x00007f451f32d121        
     0.19%  :28468   [guest.kernel.kallsyms]  [g] 0xffffffff8100bb80        
     0.19%  :28468   [guest.kernel.kallsyms]  [g] 0xffffffff8150ffc2
```

I read [here](http://www.brendangregg.com/Slides/SCALE2015_Linux_perf_profiling.pdf) that I need to install dbgsym package which I cant understand exactly. (Note: I am not new to linux but not an expert either). I have also tried to run the above command in the root folder because I read somewhere that it may be the issue of absolute path etc. but to no avail.

I want to know how do tackle this problem of unknowns in perf kvm report.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So RHEL is your host and Ubuntu is your guest?

As you may already know, the `-dbgsym` packages are compiled with debug symbols included. The ubuntu wiki has a page on [getting -dbgsym.ddeb packages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages) which may be of use to you. There is also a page on [debugging kvm](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKVM) although it doesn't look too helpful.